# i can not add an Two dimensional array property to a relationship

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher

i test Two dimensional array like:

```
RETURN [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]] AS collection
```

it works.

but , when i try to add an Two dimensional array property to a relationship like:

```
MATCH (station_44:STATION {id:44}), (station_38:STATION {id:38}) CREATE UNIQUE (station_44)-[:test2 { path:[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]] } ]->(station_38)
```

I get error: Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties.

How can i do it? is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have an array containing an array as node or relationship property values.

You can only have an array of one primitive type, for eg `int` or `string`.

[Documentation reference on property values](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-values-detailed.html)

Anyway, if you need to query the subdimension of the arrays, then your model is definitely wrong, so I would suggest to redefine your model for the queries you need to do.

If you just want to store it as a property for later retrieval, you can store it as json String and serialize/deserialize at the application level.

Comment: i want to store an Latitude,Longitude array as a property . like: [[116.445552,39.951749][116.444916,39.951656]] .   As you suggest， you mean story it as JSON string like: "[[116.445552,39.951749][116.444916,39.951656]]"     right?

Comment: Yes, so encode it in json before storing, after retrieving decode json.